# cycle for gives error

Tags: r, matrix

I need to get the vector of fractions by next criteria:
I enter `n - natural number` (f.e. `n=5`), and R is needed to print the vector which consists of all fractions that have type: `i/n` for each `i=1,...,n`. I suggest that this task can be realized through `for` cycle:

```
func=function(n) {
x=lapply(output[i],)
for(i in 1:n)
output[i]=i/n
x
}
```

But R results the error in the code.
For `n=4` I want to obtain the next vector:

```
1/4
2/4
3/4
1
```

Comment: `f <- function(n) sapply(1:n, function(i) i/n); f(4)` - gives the output you want, but I think you should improve both programming and english skills...

Comment: `func <- function(n) seq_len(n) / n` -- You should look into how R uses "vectorized" operations: https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/vectorized-operations.html

Comment: You should read the errors - they are helpful! The error you are getting is probably telling you that `x=lapply(output[i],)` isn't valid syntax - you need something after that comma.